# Can you set a variable using a button and use it in another class?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, actionlistener, accessor

I want to set the a variable using a getter and setters in one class and to be able to get that value from another class

**Class 1**

```
btnLockIn = new JButton("Lock In");
    btnLockIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            a = textTable.getText();
            setTable(a);
            System.out.println(a);

        }
    });
```

This sets the table number to what the user puts in and what I want to do is get the value that they set to be used in another class. currently it in the second class by using the        getTable all i get is the default value its set as which is null.

**Class 2**

```
    Class1 log = new Class1();
    final String Table_no = log.getTable();

    JLabel lblTableNo = new JLabel("Table no: " + Table_no);
    lblTableNo.setBounds(10, 15, 100, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblTableNo);
```

This is a class that should be using the variable that is taken from the first class and displaying it in the top of the GUI. But as mentioned before its just displaying null.

I'm sure the answer is simple but is been bugging me for a while now and with my limited knowledge at Java any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are creating a new instance and then calling `getTable` on that. You need to share the same instance of `Class1`.

Comment: Could you provide what the Class2 really does? and who creates it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is: 
    `Class1 log = new Class1();`
This creates a new instance of Class1.

Think of buying a new ball and putting a sticker on it. The ball is Class1 and the button is the sticker. You're trying to buy a new ball and get the sticker off of it, but the sticker is still on the first ball. You need to access your already made class. Try using static methods.

Comment: Oh please don't advice him to use static! :|

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Class1 passed to Class2**

In `Class2`

```
Class1 log = class1;
```

and the class1 should be taken for example in constructor of `Class2`.

As user3769237 noticed, your getter should be invoked after the `ActionListener` event is triggered.

**Option 2: Class2 implements ActionListener**

In `Class1`

```
btnLockIn.addActionListener(yourClass2Instance);
```

Make `Class2` implement `ActionListener` and implenent as follows

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    a = textTable.getText();
    // do with a whatever you want
}
```